# Error installing AWS SDK for Ruby on Mac

Tags: ruby, sdk, amazon-web-services

I'm learning Ruby to access an AWS SDB created by my partner.  When I installed the AWS SDK for Ruby on my Mac, I got the following message:

WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
      /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/royclymer/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.

I'm familiar with "PATH" from my PC days but have just started using Terminal on the Mac (to run Ruby) and can't find PATH command there.  Maybe this isn't a problem, because it did say "six gems installed" but I also got several statements like "No definition for get_options."

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are trying to install a gem into your system install ruby.  You can likely resolve this issue by prefixing the gem install command with sudo.

```
sudo gem install aws-sdk
```

While this should work, its generally better to use a different solution that does not require installing gems as root (try googling rvm and rbenv).

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is not a command, it's an environment variable. To see the current content, do `echo $PATH` in your terminal. To temporarily change your `PATH` you can just re-export it like so:

```
export PATH=~/.gem:$PATH
```

For a permanent change you may want to read up on `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` as well as `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/`.